# Keep Django session data after sign-in?

Tags: django, session-state

I recently wrote shopping cart code that depends on the Session object.  It seemed the reasonable way to store data for anonymous users.

While doing a bunch of testing, I ran into an annoying problem--when users sign in part way through the checkout process (or simply while browsing for other products), Django issues a new session_key and I lose access to my session data.

Is there a way to keep the old session data?  Or is my design approach wrong?

Comment: Why not copying the session data from the old session to the new session once a user signs in?

Comment: I'm using the built-in authentication views because I'm lazy and would rather not write my own login views if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing your own SessionBackend that inherits from existing one and overrides the `cycle_key` method.

1 In your `settings.py`:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'my_app.session_backend'
```

2 `my_app.session_backend.py`:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DbSessionStore

class SessionStore(DbSessionStore):
    def cycle_key(self):
        pass
```

`cycle_key` is beeing called in `login` view after authentication.

Let me now if it works ;)

Comment: It works!  I still need to spend some time digging through the Django code to figure out if there are any security implications related to not cycling the key, but I figure it should be fairly easy to do some more work in the cycle_key function to simply re-associate cart data with the new key.

Comment: Apparently I can't add styled code to comments.  Here's my slightly expanded solution.  Thanks rafek!  https://gist.github.com/3473470

Comment: -1. This may solve the problem, but disabling a security mechanism is not how you should do things. See @AaronC.deBruyn's solution for a better way to do it.

Comment: I ended up modifying @rafek's example.  Instead of just passing, I generate a new key, re-associate the data from the old key, and continue on with the new session key.

Comment: This introduces a security vulnerability - Django specifically cycles the keys to mitigate session fixation attacks. Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.cycle_key - OWASP documentation: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation

Comment: @AaronC.deBruyn: Please go ahead and post that GitHub snippet as an answer. Answering your questions is encouraged.

Comment: @rafek pointed me in the right direction.  I think he deserves the credit.

Comment: @AaronC.deBruyn, apologies for necromancy—trying to understand your solution, do you forget to call `super().cycle_key()` in your exception handler, or do you avoid that on purpose? (talking about https://gist.github.com/darkpixel/3473470)

Comment: No worries @tony.  It's been a while since I touched that project, but I think I should be cycling the key when the exception occurs--after all there is no cart at that point, so I don't care if we lose association with it.  :)  Good luck on your project, and nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the `cycle_key()` (which is a security measure to avoid session fixation vulnerabilities), you could consider restoring the values through a decorator at the `login` and `logout` views. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849076/146289

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar. Django can change the `session_key` to mitigate session fixation vulnerabilities, so it's not suitable for a foreign key. I want something more permanent. So I'll just put the permanent identifier in `request.session['visitor_id']`:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
import string

VALID_KEY_CHARS = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits

def example_view(request):
    if not request.session.get('visitor_id'):
        self.request.session['visitor_id'] = get_random_string(32, VALID_KEY_CHARS)
    # Now code the rest of the view, using the visitor_id instead of
    # session_key for keys in your model.
    # ...
```